# Android aar include jar dependency resources folder

Tags: android, jar, dependencies, android-resources

**Hello**

While developing an Android AAR module, I encounter the following problem
My AAR module has a few jar dependencies, some of them have resources folder with error localized error messages. For some reason when I create the module AAR I noticed that Android build process exclude the resources folder from the jar dependency. The dependencies folder is an essential part since otherwise the error details are not found.

If something could shed light on the issue, I tried to create additional resources folder under main/resources//messages.properties but it didn't help.

Any help will be appreciated

here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'

    configurations {
        javadocDeps
    }


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled false
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
            testLogging {
                events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
                outputs.upToDateWhen {false}
                showStandardStreams = true
            }
        }
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true

    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
           ...
        }
        test {

        }
    }

}





//assembleDebug.dependsOn(copyResDirectoryToClasses)

dependencies {

    releaseCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    provided 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.3'
    provided 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1'
    provided 'org.codehaus.sonar-plugins:sonar-ant-task:2.2'
    provided 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    provided 'com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4'
    provided 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    provided 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestCompile files('../sdkSample/lib/qa_utils.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4'
    javadocDeps 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    javadocDeps 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    javadocDeps 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'
    javadocDeps 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1'
    javadocDeps group: 'org.mozilla', name: 'rhino', version: '1.7.7.1'
    javadocDeps group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '16.0.3'
    testCompile files('../sdkSample/lib/qa_utils.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.json:json:20171018'
    testCompile 'com.google.android:annotations:4.1.1.4'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.13.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.9.1'
    testCompile 'org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1'
}


gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    gradle.taskGraph.allTasks.each {
        if(it.project == 'sdkSample') {
            it.onlyIf { false }
        }
    }
}



//ignore all test failures - is done temporary, the final solution is test categorization
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    -> project.tasks.findAll { it.name =~ /connected.+AndroidTest/ ||
            it.name == "testDebugUnitTest" ||
            it.name =="testReleaseUnitTest" }.each {
        it.ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

Comment: would be helpful if you could show at least your gradle file.

Comment: thanks for looking at my question, unfortunately, I can't expose my code publicly it does meet our company compliance. I can show only a part of it. which section do you think will be helpful. Could you write me what section my gradle my file probably missing

Comment: please see my gradle

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `api` instead of `provided`. You can find more info from [here.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html)

As i know aar cant have transitive dependencies. You may try export `fat aar`  or you can give it a try to

```
implementation 'your.package:your_artifact:your_version' {transitive = true}
```

**PS: Dont use type @aar**

**Also known as flatDir, because flatDir dependencies DOES NOT resolve transitives)**

```
implementation 'your.package:your_artifact:your_version@aar' {transitive = true}
```

On the otherhand, you need to convert your project to maven standards. So that, you need a pom.xml file which points transitive dependencies under dependencies tag.

As you experienced jar files cant have resource files either. If you dont need to resource files, just export jar by executing `createFullJarRelease` task.

If you have to use .aar, you can add other dependencies that library uses in consumer.